# How do I display html within html?

Tags: html, clojure, escaping

Suppose I've got an html document:

```
<html>test<html>
```

And I want to display that code in a browser. Then I'd create something like:

```
<html><body>
<pre>&lt;html&gt;test&lt;html&gt;</pre>
</body></html>
```

To make the gubbins in the middle I have a function:

```
(defn html-escape [string] 
  (str "<pre>" (clojure.string/escape string {\< "&lt;", \> "&gt;"}) "</pre>"))
```

which does the above transformation for me:

```
user> (html-escape "<html>test<html>")
"<pre>&lt;html&gt;test&lt;html&gt;</pre>"
```

My question is: is that good enough, or am I going to come across html that will make that transformation break?

And a secondary question might be: does clojure have this built in? I can't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few options:

1. Roll your own.
2. Use commons StringEscapeUtils
3. If you're using hiccup, it comes with a function for this.

For #3, just use the `h` function in [hiccup.core](https://github.com/weavejester/hiccup/blob/master/src/hiccup/core.clj).

For #2, add `[org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 "3.1"]` to your dependencies, and then you can encode with

```
(org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils/escapeHtml4 "your string")
```

For #1, you can use the function hiccup uses. It's pretty small:

```
(defn escape-html
  "Change special characters into HTML character entities."
  [text]
  (.. ^String (as-str text)
    (replace "&"  "&amp;")
    (replace "<"  "&lt;")
    (replace ">"  "&gt;")
    (replace "\"" "&quot;")))
```

Any of these solutions are fine.