# clojure: howto build a string from two sequences?

Tags: clojure, lazy-sequences

I struggling with a problem for hours now... I want to build a link with values from two sequences.

```
(doseq [item photoset-name] (prn item ))
(doseq [item-name photoset-id] (prn item-name ))
```

output:

```
"AlbumTitel2"
"test"
"AlbumTitel"
"album123"
"speciale"
"neues B5 Album"
"Album Nr 2"
"72157632764328569"
"72157632769231530"
"72157632769092584"
"72157632768156156"
"72157632762740183"
"72157632724688181"
"72157632760876608"
```

Now I want to build a link like this (for every id/name):

```
<a href="http://example.com?id=72157632764328569">AlbumTitel2</a>
```

And it should be a sequence or map... anything I can iterate though.

Does anyone have an idea how to archive this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
(map #(str "<a href=\"http://example.com?id="
           %1
           "\">"
           %2
           "</a>") photoset-ids photoset-names)
```

Comment: I hope these aren't user-provided albums - make sure you escape if they are!

Comment: What do you mean? If he reads them in using edn they should be escaped, right?

Comment: I am referring to html escaping to avoid XSS. What if a user provided an album with the title `X</a><script src="hack.net/sniff.js"/>`?

Comment: How wold you do it? I don't deal with generating weblinks a lot.

Comment: This question goes into it: [html escaping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233777/how-do-i-display-html-within-html)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a map in one of two ways (I don't have Clojure handy at the moment so I can't verify):

```
(map #(prn "<a href=\"" %1 "\">" %2 "</a>") item item-name)
```

or

```
(doseq [pair (map vector item item-name)]
  (prn "<a href=\"" (first pair) "\">" (second pair) "</a>"))
```

**EDIT:** be careful using `map`; it's lazy so if you don't use the result returned by it then it might not actually be run!

This might also work:

```
(doseq [[url title] (map vector item item-name)]
  (prn "<a href=\"" url "\">" title "</a>"))
```

---

Combining items from multiple lists into pairs in a single list is commonly referred to as "zipping". The `(map vector ...)` I found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2588385/225292)

Comment: Why would you want it to be run if you don't use the result? It's the whole point of laziness, isn't it?

Comment: @lgrapenthin you are correct; however, if you're unaware that `map` is lazy in Clojure and you try to do some sort of IO operation in it, using it as a general loop construct and not consuming the result, then you might be surprised, [as I was](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046515/listbox-jlist-wont-update-dynamically-from-custom-listmodel), when nothing happens. I just thought I'd mention this in case the OP didn't know.

Comment: In the case that you linked to you were trying to invoke a function with side-effects using map. There, instead of using `doseq` as suggested in the answer you got, wrapping the call to map in a `dorun` usually performs better, as doseq should only be used when doing additional, `for`-like filtering/combining in the bindings. Btw., the map returned from the first line of your code will return a seq full of `nil`s.

Comment: Might be better to avoid doing the IO during the transformation (use str as per @lgrapenthin 's answer.

Comment: @lgrapenthin: That's not true. `map` always makes all the intermediate allocations, while `doseq` does not. For that reason alone one would expect it to be faster. Then there's the fact that `dorun` is not chunked-seq-aware, whereas `doseq` is; `doseq` inlines the body in the expansion, while `map` uses the passed-in function in a higher order fashion; etc. In simple microbenchmarks using Criterium, with only one input collection and no processing of items beyond executing a body of expressions for side effects, `doseq` wins by fairly significant margins.

Comment: Example microbenchmark: https://www.refheap.com/17369 (604 µs `doseq` vs. 987 µs `dorun map` when iterating over a range mutating a box at each step). I am of course only disagreeing with the assertion that `dorun map` should be preferred to `doseq` where both are applicable. Here `doseq` does not seem to be applicable in the first place, since the question asks for a seqable to be returned.

Comment: Better microbenchmark (results: 624 µs vs. 977 µs): https://www.refheap.com/17370

Comment: I am surprised. I remember opposite results from my own benchmarks involving file IO. Well then I'll have to look into that again.

Comment: @lgrapenthin I was using `prn` in the iterated function since that's the function the OP was using in their example -- I seem to have missed the line where they wanted something iterable as a result. As you say, it should be using `str` instead so that the returned list isn't all `nil` values.

Comment: @lgrapenthin Also, thanks for letting me know about `dorun`. I've been learning Clojure in a piecemeal fashion by reading docs for/finding functions when I need them, so I haven't had exposure to a lot of core's functions yet.